# CSS aligning fixed footer to the bottom of the min-height of a body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can anyone suggest if there's a way to keep a fixed footer not to go above a min-height of a content? (so if a min-height of a content is higher than a browser window (viewport) a fixed footer would stay above a min-height otherwise if a viewport is higher a footer should be fixed to the bottom)

i guess it's only possible to make using JS/jQuery. i would appriciate if someone could give me a tip of how to achieve that.

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 800px;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background: blue;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}
#content {
   width: 85%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 50px 0;
}
footer {
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background: blue;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

[FIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dcsf3/)

in my case a footer is always sticked to the bottom of a browser no matter what the min-height is.

Comment: I believe it's only possible with js

Comment: Do you want the fixed footer to be visible when the window is smaller than the height of the container (in this case `800px`)?

Comment: well, this is how it works now. but i want the footer not to go beyond min-height. which in my case is 800px.

Comment: I can't think of a way this can be done without JS. Twitter bootstrap has a good affix plugin that can be used for this. Or if you want to roll your own solution it will only take a few lines of code.

Comment: Use google and search for Sticky Footer

Comment: sticky footer won't solve the problem

Comment: i edited my question. hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking before. Maybe this is what you were looking for?

```
* {
      margin: 0;
    }
    html, body {
      min-height: 400px;
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
    }
    header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background: blue;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
    }
    #content {
      width: 85%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 50px 0;
    }
    footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background: blue;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dcsf3/2/)

Comment: the thing is that the footer should stay sticked to the bottom of the browser when the window height is bigger than 800px (min. height) and go down when it's less than that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand your question. I just edited my answer. So, you want it stuck to the bottom of the content and then continue being under the content? Am I understanding this correct? Or I just happened to think, if the content is longer then the window the footer should then be stuck to the bottom of the window?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do one thing:

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    /* the change is here */
    top: 800px;
}
```

But by this way your footer will be not displayed! otherwise using big screen with resolution height greater than 800px. My laptop screen is just 768px! To use no Javascript, you have to make a lot of css media query rules depends on the possible screens resolutions

http://jsfiddle.net/Dcsf3/3/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe you want something like that?

```
.b-footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
}

    .b-footer__l {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3hcCu/

Comment: thanks, i edited my question hope it's more clear what i'm trying to achieve now.